# Simple form time input within range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

So my current time input is

```
= f.input :start_time, :as => :time, :minute_step => 5
```

But I want to limit the time that the user can choose to between 9:00 and 17:00. I have tried a `:start` object but that doesn't work and I cannot find anything within the time_select helper.

Answer (score 0):

You'll almost certainly have to use some custom Javascript to address this.

Consider the following jQuery code that installs change handlers and does what you're trying to do:

```
$("#game_start_time_4i, #game_start_time_5i").change(function() {
    var start_hour_element = $("#game_start_time_4i");
    var start_minute_element = $("#game_start_time_5i");
    var start_hour = start_hour_element.val();
    var start_minute = start_minute_element.val();

    if (start_hour < "09") {
        start_hour_element.val("09");
    } else if (start_hour >= "17") {
        start_hour_element.val("17");
        start_minute_element.val("00");
    }
});
```

You can also use jQuery to simply disable all of the hours outside the range:

```
$("#game_start_time_4i").find('option').each(function() {
    var hour = +$(this).val();
    if (hour < 9 || hour > 17) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Since this doesn't disallow times like 17:30, you'll want to use it in conjunction with the change handlers above.

Finally, you can also use jQuery to remove all of the hours outside the range:

```
$("#game_start_time_4i").find('option').each(function() {
    var hour = $(this).val();
    if (hour < "09" || hour > "17") {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

This approach should also be used in conjunction with the change handlers in the first code block.

To find the exact names of the time select elements, you'll need to view the generated HTML as source.  In my case, I'm using this on a controller named "Game", so the element IDs are all prefixed with `game_`; if you're using `FooController`, you can use `foo_start_time_4i` and `foo_start_time_5i` as your element IDs.  You can have as many of these as you want on a page, as long as you make sure to change the identifiers for each time_select that you use.

Note: this can be slightly brittle if Rails changes naming convention, but it's definitely a workable approach to get range-based time entry.